# Selenium Python - Store XPath in var and extract depther hirachy XPath from var

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I sadly couldn't find any resources online for my problem. I'm trying to store elements found by XPath in a list and then loop over the XPath elements in a list to search in that object. But instead of searching in that given object, it seems that selenium is always again looking in the whole site.
Anyone with good knowledge about this? I've seen that:
//  Selects nodes in the document from the current node that matches the selection no matter where they are
But I've also tried "/" and it didn't work either.
Instead of giving me the text for each div, it gives me the text from all divs.

**My Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

result_text = []

# I'm looking for all divs with a specific class and store them in a list
divs_found = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-fixed-right-grid-col a-col-left']")

# Here seems to be the problem as it seems like instead of "divs_found[1]" it behaves like "driver" an looking on the whole site
hrefs_matching_in_div = divs_found[1].find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/gp/product/')]")

# Now I'm looking in the found href matches to store the text from it
for href in hrefs_matching_in_div:
    result_text.append(href.text)

print(result_text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.` for immediate child.Try now.

```
hrefs_matching_in_div = divs_found[1].find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@href, '/gp/product/')]")
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for solving this. I've been looking for an answer everywhere. It solves my problem. Glad you've provided a solution!